# How to filter datetime using gremlin_python

Tags: python, gremlin, gremlinpython

I want to filter the vertex based out of a date. I don't know from which package i have to refer the **gt**

```
graph = Graph()
remote_connection = DriverRemoteConnection(gremlin, 'g')
g = graph.traversal().withRemote(remote_connection)
serviceAcc=g.V().hasLabel('ServiceAccount').has('creationTime',TextP.gt(datetime.datetime('2021-10-05'))).valueMap(True).toList()
remote_connection.close()
```

Comment: @kelvin: when i use [from gremlin_python.process.traversal import P] I ended up getting exception '{TypeError}an integer is required (got type str)'.

Answer (score 1):

The predicates like `gt` and `lt` are part of the `P` class.  So you would use `P.gt`.

**UPDATED to show an example on 2021-10-26**

Using the Python console connected to a Gremlin server (Amazon Neptune in this case)

```py
>>> import datetime

>>> g.addV('now').property('date',datetime.datetime(2021,10,25,19,41,0)).next()

v[3ebe5ef4-512a-a2e1-e519-34583b96dd1c]

>>> g.V().has('date',P.gte(datetime.datetime(2021,10,25,19,0,0))).next()

v[3ebe5ef4-512a-a2e1-e519-34583b96dd1c]

>>> g.V().has('date',P.gte(datetime.datetime(2021,10,25,19,0,0))).valueMap().next()

{'date': [datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 25, 19, 41)]}
```

Comment: When i use [from gremlin_python.process.traversal import P] I ended up getting exception '{TypeError}an integer is required (got type str)' for the above query.

Comment: The Python `datetime` is looking for a slightly different format not a an ISO 8601 string. For reference https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Comment: I updated the answer to show an example.